# Strange unmatched curly brace in OpenCV

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opencv

I am using the version of OpenCV for iPhone, and I have encountered a somewhat strange error. In using the stitcher, some of the imported headers are now complaining about an unmatched '{' on this line:

```
enum { NO, FEATHER, MULTI_BAND };
```

`NO` is a macro from objc.h which is defined as

```
#define NO              __objc_no
```

And the compiler is expecting a '}' to match the opening of the enum, even though there is one just a little later on. What is happening?

Comment: Ugh, Xcode does this when you try to import objC into a c file on your end of the spectrum.  Check that your imports are correct, and that the files they're going into contain the proper extensions.

Comment: It looks right to me. Strange.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been having the same problem for a long time and I have just now discovered a workaround. As you stated correctly it is a problem with definition of the NO-makro in UIKit. What you need to do is go to your .pch-file and replace

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

with

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp>
#import <opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp>
#endif
```

So your resulting .pch should look something like this:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'Project' target in the 'Project' project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp>
#import <opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

This way the NO-enums in blenders.hpp and exposure_compensate.hpp are defined before the NO-makro in UIKit.

Answer (score 6):

Swift: In your .mm file, you just have to undefine the 'NO' macro from UIKit before calling any OpenCV headers.

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#undef NO
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a much simpler fix for Swift users.

In my `.mm` file I moved  my `.h` import under  `#import<opencv2/opencv.hpp>` .

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I change the code -

```
//    enum { NO, FEATHER, MULTI_BAND };
    enum { NO_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATOR =  0, FEATHER, MULTI_BAND };
```

it works for me. 
Thanks.